# How to fix 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'There is no row at position 0.' error?

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access, oledb

I am creating a login system in VB.NET Using SQL and OLEDB (if that's helpful). I am trying to insert a new item in the table, but I keep getting an exception, How do I fix it?

I have tried simply changing the number zero in this line `Dim comd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql, Connstring)` to other numbers and to recordno which is the number of records in the table.

```
Dim sql As String = "INSERT INTO UserInfo (Username, Password, CurrentLevel) VALUES (?, ?, ?)"
Dim comd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql, Connstring)                    
comd.Parameters.AddWithValue(0, tblTable.Rows(recordno)(0))            
comd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", tblTable.Rows(2)(recordno))
comd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", tblTable.Rows(3)(recordno))
comd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CurrentLevel", tblTable.Rows(4)(recordno))
comd.ExecuteNonQuery() 'run the code to Insert back to the db file
```

I would expect the code to add another entry into the table `UserInfo` but nothing happens, except for the exception

> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: There is no row at position 0.

Comment: You seem to have inconsistent placement of your recordno index in your four parameters.  Your query only has three parameters by the way.

Comment: You have 3 question marks and 4 parameters.

Comment: What is recordno and where does it come from? `.Rows(0)(0)` is the first row, first column.

Comment: You may want to read [Can we stop using AddWithValue](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/).

Comment: I have realised the problem, I didn't actually have a table on this form which is where the error comes from, thanks for your responses!

Answer (score 0):

This indicates that no rows were in your tblTable and since you're trying to get the first row (...tblTable.Rows(0)...) it is throwing the error.

Answer (score 0):

This is difficult to read/comprehend:

```
comd.Parameters.AddWithValue(0, tblTable.Rows(recordno)(0))
```

A better practice is to use a string argument with the name of the parameter, yes I know `AddWithValue` has an overload with a number but this easily gets un-ordered and difficult to identify which parameter the number maps to, so be explicit and use a paramName:

```
comd.Parameters.AddWithValue("paramName", tblTable.Rows(recordno)(0))
```

Then we run into the actual problem:

```
tblTable.Rows(recordno)(0)
```

You've done this wrong, it should be:

```
tblTable.Rows(0)(recordno)
```